# ChartContainer Personalization

Tags: sapui5, variant, personalization

I am developing a page with chart. I want to add personalization to the chart.
From the documentation I understood that I need to set the `showPersonalization="true"` and have a method `personalizationPress="attachPersonalizationPress"`.

But after that what exactly I need to do? Also, I  want to know how can I use variant manager in the charts. These are the VizFrame charts and not the smartcharts.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [design guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/chart-toolbar/#personalization-generic):

> Developers can add a Personalization button to the app’s chart toolbar
>   to enable app-specific personalization charting (property:
>   ShowPersonalization). **The corresponding popover and details also need
>   to be implemented by the developer.**

To handle the personalization event, start from this SAPUI5 Explored [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.12/explored.html#/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.ChartContainerToolbarEnhancement/preview):

- add `attachPersonalizationPress` function to the [Contorller](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.12/explored.html#/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.ChartContainerToolbarEnhancement/code/Page.controller.js):

  ```
  function attachPersonalizationPress() {
     // do your logic here
  }
  ```
- add `attachPersonalizationPress` to personalizationPress event in the [View](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.12/explored.html#/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.ChartContainerToolbarEnhancement/code/Page.view.xml):

  ```
  <ChartContainer
          showPersonalization="true"
          personalizationPress="attachPersonalizationPress">
  ```